How to distinguish between network/server/serialization errors in granular manner?
I have a simple REST client written using RestSharp.
var opts = new RestClientOptions("http://api.muyservice.com/")
{
    // ResponseStatus should not be an Error when deserialisation failed.
    FailOnDeserializationError = false,
};

using var client = new RestClient(opts);
var request = new RestRequest("myEndpoint");
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<ResponseDto>(request);

// error handling
// network error? No, not really.
// Also an http codes 4xx/5xx, except 404
if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed) 
{
    // log network errors
}
else if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // http request completed successfully, but server returned non-200 results.
    // handle server errors
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        // extract error details from response body
    }
    else
    {
        // handle generic server error
    }
}
else if (response.Data == null)
{
    // serialization failed
}
else
{
    // all ok, handle the results
}

I want to handle network/server/serialisation errors in the different ways (e.g. log different details, suggest to adjust timeouts in the config in case of request timeout and so on), but I have not found the straightforward way to distinguish between the error types (network/server/deserialisation) and make the granular error handling.
What problems I found so far:

the response.ResponseStatus will be Error in case of network error or in case of server errors 5xx/4xx (except 404).
in case of a timeout the ResponseStatus will be TimedOut, but the ErrorMessage and the ErrorException will be Operation was canceled (no single word about the timeout)
IsSuccessfulStatusCode will say Success for http 404 code.
there is no dedicated error state for the deserialisation (which is understandable because different deserialisers can be used). So if null is the valid value for the ResponseDto, then there is no way to diagnose deserialisation errors at all?

Is there is a straightforward way to handle the error in RestSharp in a granular way?

Timeouts should be handle with an exception handler (try/catch).  Most cases when you do not get a 200 OK the body (response.Data) is empty.  Some servers will return detailed data of the error in the body so instead of testing for respse.Data == NULL it is better to test for StatusCode != 200.

According to the documentation, the ExecuteAsync<T>() newer throws any exception, so I can't handle timeouts with a try/catch. And anyway, if I'm going to use the method that throws, then I'm not sure it is possible to distinguish between "timed out" and "cancelled by user using the cancellation token" in the straightforward way.

About checking the StatusCode != 200 - exactly! I do it in the sample - check for 200, then (optionally, for the code 400) check the response body for the error details. And only if the status is 200 I try to handle the response.Data. But, again, the status might be 200, but the deserialisation of the response into the DTO may fail and I want to handle this case separately.

Answer to first response. ExecuteAsync() may not give an exception but underlining methods may give an exception.  You can set a variable when user cancels so you can distinguish between the timed out and cancel events.

To  handle the 200 case when the DTO fails you need an exception handler in the section of code that does deserialization.

@jdweng, I don't own the deserialization code, it belongs to the RestSharp. So I can't add try/catch there. The question is specifically about the RestSharp lib and it's usage. And specifically about it's correct usage. Actually, I have the working solution, but it looks like a spagetti and I'm wondering if I'm missing something and there is a normal straightforward way to do the things.

Does the RestSharp have a "THROW"?
